# best performance database design to store students exams result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

previously i thought that it's easy to store exams data in simple table like this :

```
id
subject_id
student_id
mark
date
```

but i noticed that it is very stupid idea cuz it makes database very huge 
let's assume that we have school with 5000 students and there are 12 subjects for each students per month ... it means that our exams table will contain  5000*12*10 = 600000 row per year ,, ok what about if we decided to know student history from joining date to current date 
.. i think it's very stupid and i think also there are optimum solutions to make another design to fit my needs ....
i need to store exams data in another lighter way 
thank's in advance :)

Comment: 5000 students will take 12 exams every *month*??

Comment: Anyway, you're not storing any duplicate data here. It takes up how much space it takes up. There's not really a "lighter" way.

Comment: 600k rows a year over 5 years still is only about 3M rows.  Assuming around 40 bytes per datarecord + some indexes you'll consume around 100 bytes of storage per record, which brings us to a total data storage need of 300MB for 5 years of activity, which by no means classifies as "huge" or even "big"...  The basic design is OK, I'd stick to it.

Comment: Your current design is not that bad.  However, my idea by your standards would make it more stupid.  However, if in real life, different exams had different weights regarding the final mark, it would be advantageous.

Comment: If you have to record `N` exams you need `N` rows. The best design is 3 tables, 1 with the `student`, one with the `exam` and 1 association with attributes which I assume is the one that you are showing

Comment: thank's a lot for answers :)

Comment: ok then i will complete my task as i mentioned ?

Comment: @ZiadELNaggar That seems to be the consensus - good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

Table Student stores name, etc

Table Subject has subject names such as Reading, Writing and Arithmetic, and maybe a MinimumPassingMark.

Table Exam has ExamId, ExamDate, and SubjectID.  It may also have PercentageOfOverallGrade

Table StudentExam has StudentID, ExamId, and mark.

Subjects and exams have a one to many relationship (one subject can have many exams, each exam has one subject.  Students and exams have a many to many relationship.

So if you want to know if Johnny can read, it's as simple as.

```
select case 
when sum(mark) * PercentageOfOverallGrade >= then 'pass' else 'no' end result
from Student s join StudentExam se on s.StudentId = se.StudentId
join Subject su on se.SubjectId = su.SubjectId
where s.name = 'Johnny'
and su.name = 'Reading'
```